# Why does my code always end with undefined?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I wrote this JavaScript code, but it always ends **undefined**mycode? What have I done wrong/ how can I prevent this in the future. I am running my code through the chrome javascript console.

Here is my code

```
    //Reverse a string
//-------------------------//
//Input a string

var string = prompt("Please enter string");
            //console.log(string);

//Find length of string

var stringLength = string.length;
            //console.log(stringLength);

//Creating an empty string for outputting answer

var reversedString = "";

//Start from length of the string and work backwards, inputting letter 1 at a time.
for (var i = stringLength; i >= 0; i--){
    reversedString += string[i];
                //console.log(string[i]);
}

//Outputting the reversed string;
alert(reversedString);
```

Thanks for any answers in advance

Comment: What is undefined? The code itself cannot "be" undefined.

Comment: if i input hello, the output is undefinedolleh. So the code is working as it should, but the word undefined is placed in front of it automatically

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the string showing in the `alert()` and not the result in the console.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make the problem clearer.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. First time I have asked a question here, and was amazed by the quick response. All the answers were what I was looking for, and I will hopefully progress quickly to a stage where I don't make these noob mistakes so often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your loop from

```
for (var i = stringLength; i >= 0; i--){
```

to

```
for (var i = stringLength-1; i >= 0; i--){
```

The problem is, the array indices in javascript are 0 based.

Lets say the string entered in the prompt is "abc", the length of the string is 3. In the loop, you access it as `string[3]` which is undefined. Hence the error.

Here is the fiddle demonstrating the updated code:

- http://jsfiddle.net/rf1vmyzg/

Comment: Why? For a beginner, an **explanation** would definitely be more helpful.

Comment: Because the a[a.length] is _undefined_, by definition for all arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do string[i] instead do string.charAt(i); Also change stringLength to stringLength - 1. That should fix your problem.  If you want this to work across different browsers use charAt notation. Javascript arrays start at 0 not 1 that is why you do length - 1 to get the last element. For example:
for a 10 element array indexes are 0-9. 10 is outside the boundaries of the array.

```
for (var i = (stringLength - 1); i >= 0; i--){
reversedString += string.charAt(i);
```

This is the correct answer.

Comment: Nope, that's not the issue. *edit:* The loop variable is the problem, not the bracket notation.

Comment: The lack of `charAt` will cause the code to break on Internet Explorer.  Whether that is good or bad is left to your conscience.

Comment: If you want this to work across browsers use charAt not [] this will be a problem @Felix Kling

Comment: But it's not he problem the op is facing and you originally claimed it was.

Comment: I am helping him for future problems he might face.  I also told him his problem he is asking about...so what's your question?

Comment: I don't have any question. I'm just pointing out that your *original* has only been about `charAt`, which was unrelated to the OP's problem (and thus your original answer has not been useful). The answer is OK since you have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

adding string[i] is the last thing this code does before alerting you, so therefore the last string[i], (first element in your array, I assume) has the value of undefined.

```
for (var i = stringLength; i >= 0; i--){
        reversedString += string[i];
                //console.log(string[i]);
}
```

I do not know on the top of my head why this is, but I know that it is **always** a good idea to stick to conventions, and the one for for loops is:

```
for(var i = 0; i < [length variable];i++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right code

```
for (var i = stringLength-1; i >= 0; i--){
    reversedString += string[i];
    console.log(string[i]);
}
```